# Does ARC keep track of the const char* produced by [NSString UTF8String]?

Tags: objective-c, c, automatic-ref-counting

Is the `const char*` valid?
Does ARC keep track of the pointer returned by this function?

```
const char* getUrl()
{
    // retrieve an url with obj-c
    NSString *maybeTmp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"some url"];
    return [maybeTmp UTF8String];
}
```

*This code is used as a bridge. A C library is going to call this function.*

I would guess that ARC doesn't keep track of that pointer and will release this NSString once the function getUrl() returns, leaving the pointer as non valid.

- Is the pointer non-valid after the end of the function?
- If non-valid, is there a way to explicitly ask ARC to keep track of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, ARC does not (and cannot) manage lifetimes of non-object types. If you take a look at the [documentation for `-[NSString UTF8String]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411189-utf8string?language=objc), you can also see the following:

> This C string is a pointer to a structure inside the string object, which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object and will certainly not have a longer lifetime. Therefore, you should copy the C string if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which you use this property.

The UTF-8 string you get back has a maximum lifetime of the lifetime of the source `NSString` (which ARC will clean up at the end of the function), so if you need to hold on to the string, you'll need to make a copy using `strdup` or similar (and manage the lifetime yourself).

Comment: Indeed, the doc is pretty self explanatory. So it means that I should only use UTF8String to copy that C string somewhere else, even if the lifetime of NSString have not ended up yet? I would have not expect this, thanks

Comment: yeah I am just surprised of that part of the doc `which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object`, which basically means that even if I keep the NSString alive somewhere (let's say using static or as a global var), the pointer might be invalid at a certain point in time

Comment: @itMaxence Sorry, deleted my original comment instead of editing it like I'd meant to. This can happen in vary rare circumstances (you have a _lot_ of tagged pointer strings, get all of their `UTF8String` values in a tight loop, and drain the current autoreleasepool before using the `UTF8String` values), but this is exceedingly rare.

Comment: @itMaxence If you want to be really safe, yes, copy the UTF-8 string before using it, and certainly do so before passing the value along to different functions (which can do whatever they want).

Comment: Basically, it's not always safe to call `-UTF8String` inside of an autorelease pool, then using the result outside of the autorelease pool. If you call `-UTF8String` and use it in the same scope (without something doing fiddly things with your autorelease pool, which is really difficult if not impossible in ARC), you should be safe.

Comment: yeah your example easily show how this could end up. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is the pointer non-valid after the end of the function?

You are correct. ARC keeps track only of memory allocated to reference-counted objects. Sinc `char*` returned by `UTF8String` does not refer to a reference-counted object, ARC does not know of its existence.

> If non-valid, is there a way to explicitly ask ARC to keep track of it?

No, because `char*` lacks "infrastructure" for keeping reference count. You could either return a reference-counted object which encloses your `char*`, or use `malloc`, make a copy, and let the caller `free` the string.

Comment: How do you add 1 to the retain count of the pointer and make `NSString` not dispose it?